# Selecting items in a ManytoMany relationship with JPQL/Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, playframework, jpql

How can I easily select records of model Article where the Category is a category with id x.
There is a ManytoMany relationship between Article and Category. (the link field int eh Article model is categories.)

I have to build the query, as it provides a list with available articles according to a set of variables. E.g. I tried something like (but clearly doesn't work):

```
    if(categoryFilter != null){
        sql += "ANY categories.id = " + categoryFilter.id + " AND " ;
    }
```

And then for the query:

```
("site.app = ? AND " + sql + "removed = 0", app)
```

I have done it before but cannot remember.
I am using Hibernate on the Play! Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select article from Article article
inner join article.categories category
where category.id = :categoryId
```

See the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins) on HQL and associations and joins.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the answer as it is the right answer, but it there another way? Creating the inner join causes a problem with a paginate module I use. As such I cannot add anything before the 'WHERE' statement.

Comment: I don't see any other way, other than fixing the paginate module.